# Placing a span at bottom of div (Horizontal displacement issue)

Tags: html, css

I know the general rule of thumb is research before asking questions, and I'm looking at a lot if different sources. Not to much luck here.

My end goal is to have the text centered and at the bottom of the div. Simple as that.

But when I use the code given by other sources, it's not centered in the actual div.

HTML:

```
<div class="fbox" id="breast">
        <span class="title">Breast Procedures</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
<span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fbox" id="facial">
        <span class="title">Facial Procedures</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
<span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fbox" id="body">
        <span class="title">Body Procedures</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
<span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fbox" id="surgery">
        <span class="title">Non-Surgical Procedures</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
<span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title{
    font-size:16px;
    margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
font-weight:600;
}
.fbox{
width: 250px;
height: 300px;
background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
-moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}
.main-content ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.main-content ul{
    margin:0 auto;
}
.read{
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
 position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jkuk6v6/)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close!

**SOLUTION:**

*Replace:*

```
.read {
  height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

*With:*

```
.read {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.fbox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(139, 139, 139);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.main-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main-content ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.read {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox" id="breast">
  <span class="title">Breast Procedures</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
</div>
<div class="fbox" id="facial">
  <span class="title">Facial Procedures</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
</div>
<div class="fbox" id="body">
  <span class="title">Body Procedures</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
</div>
<div class="fbox" id="surgery">
  <span class="title">Non-Surgical Procedures</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="read">View Descriptions</span>
</div>
```

---

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/8g1ma595/)**